# Move Chart.js horizontal bar chart labels to the right

Tags: javascript, charts, angular-chart, chart.js2

How do you move the labels on horizontal Chart.js bar charts from the left to the right? Here are the current labels, on the left. The bar should still go from left to right, but the labels should all be to the far right of the chart, as if they were floating right.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this plugin for chart.js:
https://github.com/tomsouthall/Chart.HorizontalBar.js

Unfortunately, I don't think there's a functionality to render the text on the right hand side. You might need to write your own `draw` function

Comment: I think this is right - I end up making my own directive. I had a relatively simple chart to display so it wasn't too hard.